# Processing this form

Tags: php, html, forms

I was given this form by a designer who built it in html and I need to create some php to process the form. However, when I tested the form to see if it would pass variables, $_POST was empty. When, however, I changed the method to get, I could access the variables fine. Can anyone see where the error is?

Here is the code:

```
<form action="process/appointment.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="text/plain" id="appointments">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Name..." name="contactName"  style="width:150px;"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Contact Telephone..." name="contactTel"  style="width:150px;"/>
    <!--<input type="image" src="images/send_purple.gif" alt="send appointment request" style="margin-top:0; height:auto; border:none;"/>-->
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**EDIT**

Here is the page I was using to test the receipt of the variables:

```
<?php
print_r($_POST); print_r($_GET); 
?>
```

$_POST returns an empty array when the form is set to post, but $_GET returns the values when the for is set to get.

Comment: How were you testing the variables to see if they were empty? Show your receiving PHP page.

Comment: Did you try removing the `enctype` from the `<form>` tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your enctype is wrong, you need enctype="multipart/form-data"

Swap this line :

`<form action="process/appointment.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="text/plain" id="appointments">`

to

`<form action="process/appointment.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="appointments">`

Comment: There is no `<input type="file">`

Comment: You are right, but this will work in any case, with or without file upload

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I wasn't aware that text/plain didn't allow the data to be used via the post method.

Comment: Or just leave no `enctype`, which will default to `enctype="aplication/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, which is a smaller transfer than `multipart/form-data`, and just as easily processed by PHP.

Answer (score 1):

`enctype="text/plain"` doesn't make much sense. Remove it.

If it is doing anything at all, it is telling the browser to encode the data in a way that PHP can't convert to `$_POST`.